# show or hide div depending on dynamic value in combo box jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a combobox called **select_person** ={typeA, typeB}.

When an option is chosen I want to show other combobox **has_id**={has_id, has_no_id}

Now depending on value chosen in typeA or typeB and depending on that has_id or has_no_id I want to show (or keep hidden) the respective div.

So If the registry happens to have an id and is typeA I will show only an input field, but if is typeA and has no ID i will display 3 input fields, same for typeB.

to do so I am doing something like:

```
$(function () {
    $('#select_person').change(function () {
        $('#has_id').show();
        if ($('#select_person').val() == 'typeA') {
            $("#has_id").append("<option>" + $("#typeA_has_id").val() + "</option>");
            $("#has_id").append("<option>" + $("#typeA_has_no_id").val() + "</option>");
        }

        if ($('#select_person').val() == 'typeB') {
            $("#has_id").append("<option>" + $("#typeB_has_id").val() + "</option>");
            $("#has_id").append("<option>" + $("#typeB_has_no_id").val() + "</option>");
        }


    });
});


$(function () {
    $('#has_id').change(function () {
        $('.persons').hide();
                $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
            });      

    });
});
```

and html

```
<Select id="select_person">
    <option value="0">Select person</option>
    <option value="typeA">typeA</option>
    <option value="typeB">typeB</option>
</Select>

<Select id="has_id" style="display:none"></Select>

<div id="person1" class="persons" style="display:none">
    <div class="form-left">Type A has id *</div>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-input"
    />
</div>
<div id="person1" class="persons" style="display:none">
    <div class="form-left">Type A has No id *</div>
    <input type="text" id="id" name="id" class="form-input"
    />
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-input"
    />
    <input type="text" id="address" name="address" class="form-input"
    />
</div>

<div id="person2" class="persons" style="display:none">
    <div class="form-left">Type B has id *</div>
    <input type="text" id="nameB" name="nameB" class="form-input"
    />
</div>
<div id="person2" class="persons" style="display:none">
    <div class="form-left">Type B has No id *</div>
    <input type="text" id="idB" name="idB" class="form-input"
    />
    <input type="text" id="nameB" name="nameB" class="form-input"
    />
    <input type="text" id="addressB" name="addressB" class="form-input"
    />
</div>
```

but isnot working, could you help me out? [here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LEfbX/)

Comment: `$("#typeA_has_id")` put light on it plz.

Comment: well actually I want to put values (has_id, has_no_id) on `#has_id` combobox, from that point the code is not correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what is happening in your code and html markup:

1. `Your markup is invalid` since it `used same ids for multiple elements` on same page.
2. Its also not clear how would you determine to put values in `$("#typeA_has_id").val()`.
3. and you had a `});` extra closing at the end as mentioned in other answers as well.

and if you want to put some values in the `option` list of your `$('#has_id')` then you can try with this one.

```
$("<option/>").val('a').text('a').appendTo("#has_id");
```

Although i have done something if you would like to see:

#### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LEfbX/23/)

#### changed html:

```
<div id="person-A-withID" class="persons" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="person-A-withoutID" class="persons" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="person-B-withID" class="persons" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="person-B-withoutID" class="persons" style="display:none"></div>
```

#### jQuery:

```
$(function () {
   $('#has_id').show();
   $('#select_person').change(function () {
     $('.persons').hide();
     if ($('#select_person').val() == 'typeA') {
        $("#has_id").html('');
        $("<option/>").val('0').text('--Choose Type A--').appendTo("#has_id");
        $("<option/>").val('person-A-withID').text('person-A-withID').appendTo("#has_id");
        $("<option/>").val('person-A-withoutID').text('person-A-withoutID').appendTo("#has_id");
     }

     if ($('#select_person').val() == 'typeB') {
        $("#has_id").html('');
        $("<option/>").val('0').text('--Choose Type B--').appendTo("#has_id");
        $("<option/>").val('person-B-withID').text('person-B-withID').appendTo("#has_id");
        $("<option/>").val('person-B-withoutID').text('person-B-withoutID').appendTo("#has_id");
     }
  });

  $('#has_id').change(function () {
    $('.persons').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you have extra `});` at the end of the document...

you have two ids with a same name `person1`..which is invalid HTML markup.. either remove it..and use classes

**updated** from your comment

i have created this example fiddle..reading your comment not sure if this is what you want.. but i am sure this will get you started

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/LEfbX/18/)

Comment: Is there a better way to gen a combo box with fixed values depending on selected person?,

Comment: yes there is.. but you need to explain what you need properly since.. the appended option cannot be found in yourprovide code `$("#typeA_has_id").val()`.. this one.. what you actaully need here

Comment: The desired output is to display a div, depending first on the type of person, and then if the person has an id or has not an id. As there are 2 kinds of persons, and 2 possibilities there are 4 divs, the final div that must be showed is the one that satisfies both conditions, the issue here is I want to generate the second combo box dynamically , maybe that is not the approach

Comment: that is fine.. can you elaborate dynamically as in how.. you want to add some text in the second option which is already there.. or some values...

Comment: Hi Bipen, good answer. I just updated the fiddle so the first option is 'select type' enabling the user to select typeApersonHas without clicking on typeApersonHasNo first. [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jjay225/LEfbX/20/)

Comment: yes thanks.. :) :) @jjay225.. i forgot about that..:)..cheers

Comment: That is a really cool answer, however is there any way to reset the things when user goes over again, I mean, if the user decides to switch option and pick other person, the combo box will show the 2 values and then the other 2 values from other person, showing A has, A has not, B has, B has not... Hope I explain the issue

Comment: i am not getting you this time.. hopw @jjay225 fiddle solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

One minor mistake : }); extra

http://jsfiddle.net/LEfbX/1/

```
$(function () {
    $('#has_id').change(function () {
        $('.persons').hide();
                $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
            });
```